# How to optimize speed of query EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

i've a query as well as:

```
var query = unitOfWork.Ticket_Repository
                     .FindByQueryAsNoTracking(e => e.BusinessPageId == bpid && e.Status != p2 && e.Status != p3)
                     .Where(e => e.TicketParaphs
                                 .Where(x => x.ParaphRole == p1)
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
                                 .FirstOrDefault()
                                 .ReceiveId == User.ID);
```

this query isn't optimize because the query executing in low speed.

How to optimize this query?
thanks.

Comment: What is `FindByQueryAsNoTracking`? What does `query.ToString()` show?

Comment: @MojtabaNava its impossible to tell from what youve posted. You need to post the repository method `.FindByQueryAsNoTracking()`. From what youve posted though, I can already tell that this method returns much more data than you need since you have a long `.Where` clause filtering the results further. You need to implement a repository method for your use case that does ALL the filtering in a query instead of executing a query and then filtering the in memory results. i.e: return only the data you need from the db (what youve posted isnt a query. its calling a method that is querying the db)

Comment: Question: the Method `FindByQueryAsNoTracking()` impelemented below:

 `public IEnumerable<T> FindByAsNoTracking(Expression<Func<T, bool» predicate)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = Dbset.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
            return query;
        }`

if we use `FindByAsQuery ` that impelemented below:


 `public IQueryable<T> FindByQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool» predicate)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = Dbset.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
            return query;
        }`

The Speed will get better??

Comment: Its A Good Question.It's always been a question for me